# RE: VBA - (VLOOKUP) + (VALUE +1)

Tags: excel, vba, button, vlookup

I am completely new to VBA and an amateur to Excel. I am currently trying to learn VBA and so decided to set myself an achievable goal for my own progression. This project is the creation of a tool for documenting and presenting feedback.

Sheet 1, Cell B2 will be my cell range that'll be used for the VLOOKUP to refer to, this is a unique identifier.

B2:B25 is information that's brought from a table in sheet 2 via a standard VLOOKUP formula and contains all relevant information on the person the unique ID is associated with.

I am trying to add a button in C6 which looks up the unique ID in sheet 2 and adds one to the value within a specific cell.

For example: Sheet 1:

```
Column A          Column B         Column C       
Problem 1         Count            Button to +1
                  (VLOOKUP used)   (Macro Button)
```

Sheet 2: Table Ranges from A:W

- A: Employee Number (Unique Identifier)
- B: Name of employee
- C: Training Status
- D:W: Problems 1 - 20 (With count to how many of these problems the employee has encountered / made).

I have so far discovered that:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Value + 1
```

Works for adding +1 to the value declared in Sheet 2, D2.

What I'm struggling with is introducing a VLOOKUP function so that the button first finds the employee number declared in Sheet 1:B2 then +1 to the value.

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image: (image format not supported, please upload again)]

Comment: have you actually attempted to write the code to introduce the vlookup function? If so, please post what you have tried. then we can help you get it right. read [mcve] or [ask] for more

Comment: You are actually after `match` I believe.  Then you can offset or do what you wish with the value returned.  `rownumber=application.worksheetfunction.match("lookingfor",range,false)`

Comment: If i can suggest a few learning steps to achieve what you are trying to do: `variables` - learning about variables and setting them is very important. `currentrow, nextrow, lastrow, etc` is important to be able to determine the row you want to work with dynamically (and eventually the columns as well). `FOR LOOP`  - once you got the first 2 sorted, a loop will help you get through all your cells and gather the data you need.

Comment: Hello all,

Thank you for your timely replies, the above image is as far as I have gotten so far with the VBA.

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Value + 1" actually works to +1 to the value in D2, however I need a way to first match/vlookup using Sheet1:B1 as cell reference and then look up that employee number on the table within Sheet2, Then +1 to the value in that employee's "problem" box if that makes sense?